# Is this phrase gramatically correct?

Tags: grammar

> 英語学を続けることのため、アメリカを洋行したは俺が１７歳のときに。

I'm more or less a grammar mess, I started to learn japanese short ago and I ended up getting really confused about the whole sentence. I wanted to say something like:

> When I was 17 I traveled to America in order to complete my english studies.

Could you guys help me pretty please?